# How to handle applications that used outdated shared libraries?

Tags: shared-library, ncurses

I'm trying to run GDB on a rolling release version of Linux that is looking for libncurses.so.5, but the system has version 6 installed. I've seen solutions where people use ln to link libncurses.so.5 to version 6, but that doesn't seem like a good practice (things might be deprecated/removed in the latest).

Is it acceptable to link older libraries to newer ones or is there a better practice?

More details about the specific problem:

- Manjaro Linux with kernel 5.8
- Application (STCubeIDE) was not installed from the pacman repository (manually installed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it acceptable to link older libraries to newer ones

No.

The programs may crash at any time because of binary incompatibilities. And in general, it's a stupid idea to mess with system files (e.g. everything under `/usr`) other than with the distro tools (`apt`, `yum`, etc).

> is there a better practice?

keep the older libraries around (e.g. under `/opt/oldlibs`) and let the programs use them via the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. Details in the [ld.so(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) manpage.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it acceptable to link older libraries to newer ones or is there a better practice?

It may or may not work depending on the functions being used.

Generally it's a bad practice but if you don't want to chase down old libraries and your old application(s) work with this hack, no one will object.

Answer (score 0):

no - according to its [website](https://discover.manjaro.org/packages/ncurses), Manjaro has ncurses 6.2, and since it reuses packages from Arch, its [PKGBUILD](https://github.com/archlinux/svntogit-packages/blob/packages/ncurses/trunk/PKGBUILD) script tells us that it's using ABI 6, which is not binary-compatible with ncurses 5.

For instance, gdb has a mode to display debugging information in a terminal, using ncurses.  The highlighting and line-drawing characters will not display properly if you force it to use ncurses6 when it has been compiled for ncurses5.  That is because the size of the data structure for each cell on the screen is different between ABI 5 and ABI 6.

If you do that (link the ncurses6 libraries to pretend that they're ncurses5), and attempt to report a bug, you'll only get pointed to the release notes (for [ncurses 6.0](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/announce-6.0.html#h2-release-notes)) and [FAQ](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html).

If I had to maintain something like that, I'd compile ncurses for ABI 5 (which you can do with ncurses6, as documented: only the *default* values for the configure script have changed).